# Trouble converting malformed ISO8601-formatted varchar to timestamp

Tags: sql, string, datetime, presto, trino

I was trying to convert a timestamp *string* with the following format into a timestamp format but encountered an error as such:

```
Invalid format: "20201216T090000+0000" is malformed at "0000+0000"
```

**Original Query**

```sql
SELECT from_iso8601_timestamp(date_ts)
FROM
...
```

I thought of applying substr to retrieve `20121216T09` only as a string, which I know would work with `from_iso8601_timestamp`. But any other advice would be appreciated!

Comment: One possible ISO 8601 timestamp could be `'2020-12-16T09:00:00+00:00'`. However, ANSI SQL does not like the _optional_ `T`, so I'd go with  `'2020-12-16 09:00:00+00:00'`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`from_iso8601_timestamp()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_timestamp) supports format with dashes and colons:

```
presto> SELECT from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-12-16T09:00:00+00:00');
            _col0
-----------------------------
 2020-12-16 09:00:00.000 UTC
```

In the case input is formatted like `20201216T090000+0000`, the [`parse_datetime()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#parse_datetime) would be more appropriate.